# ML:Data set Sizes Small, Medium or Large

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

What is the range for small,medium or large data set sizes in machine learning problems? This was asked in one of the interview and I could not answer it.How we would know if our data set falls in small, medium or large category?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the size of the data might control issues relating to generalization, data imbalance, and difficulty in approaching the global optimum.

However, it has to do also with the application itself. On the quality of the data. On the questions you want to answer based on the data.

Generally, the goal is to minimize biased and variance. One efficient way to achieve this is by training with more data. Less data could make the predictive models really sensitive. But for some applications less data can also indicate significant patterns.

Another way to indicate whether you data is small or big imagine the scenario where your data consist of 20 columns and 10 rows . That's 200 cells. A dataset with 10 columns and 20 rows would be considered larger even though the total number of cells is still 200. In the latter, the number of samples is bigger.

Another point or view is the classification problems. Imagine you have a big imbalanced dataset  where the dependent variable is 99% of the times yes and 1% of the times no. On the other hand, you have a smaller dataset with approximately 50-50 distribution in the samples of the dependent variable. The latter could again be considered a more effective dataset for training.

Keep in mind that there is a variety of a techniques which you can use to deal with small datasets.